# Getting error while inserting data in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, execute-script

I am new to Python and started off with sqlite.
I have two csv transaction.csv and users.csv from where I am reading the data and writing to the sqlite database.Below is the snippet

```
import csv
import sqlite3 as db



def readCSV_users():
    with open('users.csv',mode='r') as data:
         dr = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=',')
         users_data = [(i['user_id'], i['is_active']) for i in dr if i['is_active']=='True']
         #---------------------
    return users_data
    
def readCSV_transactions():
    with open('transactions.csv',mode='r') as d:
         dr = csv.DictReader(d, delimiter=',')
         trans_data = [(i['user_id'], i['is_blocked'],i['transaction_amount'],i['transaction_category_id']) for i in dr if i['is_blocked']=='False']
         #---------------------
    return trans_data
 
def SQLite_connection(database):
 
    try:
        # connect to the database
        conn = db.connect(database)
        print("Database connection is established successfully!")
        conn = db.connect(':memory:')
        print("Established database connection to a database\
        that resides in the memory!")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        return cur,conn
    except exception as Err: 
       print(Err)

      
def dbQuery(users_data,trans_data,cur,conn):
  try:
    cur.executescript(""" CREATE TABLE if not exists users(user_id text,is_active text); 
    CREATE TABLE if not exists transactions(user_id text,is_blocked text,transaction_amount text,transaction_category_id text);
    INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?),users_data;
    INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (?,?,?,?),trans_data""")
    conn.commit()
    a=[]
    rows = curr.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
    for r in rows:
        a.append(r)
    return a
  except Err: 
       print(Err)
  finally: 
      conn.close()
      

    


if __name__ == "__main__":
  database='uit'
 
  users_data=readCSV_users()
  trans_data=readCSV_transactions()
  curr,conn=SQLite_connection(database)
  print(dbQuery(users_data,trans_data,curr,conn))
```

But I am facing below error.I believe the `?` is throwing the error in executescript

```
cur.executescript(""" CREATE TABLE if not exists users(user_id text,is_active text);
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "users_data": syntax error
```

Any pointers to resolve this?

Comment: you can't use `users_data` directly in `query` - it treats it as normal string, not variable.  But other problem can be: `executescript` can't get variables and put in place `?`. You may have to run every query separatelly using `curr.execute(query, values)`

Answer (score 0):

Putting `users_data` directly in query is wrong. It treats it as normal string.

But it seems `executescript` can't use arguments.
You would have to put values directly in place of `?`.
Or you have to use `execute()`

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?);", users_data)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (?,?,?,?)", trans_data)
```